# How can admins be able to view all items in sharepoint list while other users should be able to see only theirs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am new to SharePoint online and it is one of the most confusing ones.

I imported an excel into my SharePoint list which has the data about my company's employee's leaves. My requirement is that my HRs and top-level managers should be able to view all leave balances while other users should be able to view theirs individually.

So far I tried the following:

List Settings> Advanced Settings and did the following
[image]

Then I went to Views>All Items and did the following

[image: View]

This helped me view only my leave balances.

Then I went to List Settings>Permissions for this List> Break Permission Inheritance. I created a group called 'Owners' which contains name of all those who should be admins that can view list entirely and assigned them permissions of **Full Control**,**Design** and **Manage Hierarchy**.

And implementing all these I still find that users can only view their own leave balances.

How should I be able to assign specific permissions to owners and individuals to already existing list?

Answer (score 0):

To override those settings, the user needs the Manage List right. Once you assign that right, you'll be able to see all items.

Comment: Where is that right present in Sharepoint online?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom roles and assign these separately to different groups of Admins and normal users.

YourSitecollectionpath/_layouts/15/editrole.aspx?role=

[image]

Comment: Hi I am unable to find it. Can you tell me where this page is present in Sharepoint Online? (Like the path not url)

Comment: Go to Site Settings > Site Permissions > Permission levels (in the top ribbon) > click on the permission level you want to change

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: There are 2 manage permissions. Hope you changed both

Comment: Yes I changed admins/owners to Full Control, Design and Approve permissions. For other users, I only selected 'Read'.

Comment: Now assign these permission levels to the groups of users

Comment: Sorry man, that didn't work out. Are you sure this works in Sharepoint Online? The above path Site Settings > Site Permissions > Permission levels (in the top ribbon) > click on the permission level  didn't give the image which you posted previously. Although I tried creating two views; one for Admin where he should see all items and one where user can only see his item. However, both admins and users are able to see both types of views.